# Display brand using MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 MySQL tables:

- produs(id, name, price)
- spec_laptop(id,id_produs -foreigkey(produs-id), brand)
- spec_telefon(id,id_produs -foreigkey(produs-id), brand)

and 2 pages:

- telefon.php (which will have a list of brands of cellphones)
- laptop.php (which will have a list of brands of laptops)

  I tried to make a query which displays names and prices from produs which:

  1. When I click a brand from telefon.php , display all cellphones names and prices who have that brand
  2. When I click a brand from laptop.php , display all laptops names and prices who have that brand

Example: (it doesn't work and I don't know why):

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.*,t3.* FROM produs as t1 join spec_laptop as t2  join spec_telefon as t3 WHERE(t1.id=t3.id_produs OR t1.id=t2.id_produs) AND t2.brand='Acer'
```

Comment: Maybe having a derp moment but what is `t1.*,t2.*,t3.*`? Are those fields or something else?

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: I have 10 products in spec_laptop and 10 products in spec_telefon...when I check a brand from (laptop.php) it displays me over 20 products (some are repeating).. When I check a brand from (laptop.php) I want to display only products from spec_laptop that have brand like the one i'm checked...same for 9telefon.php)...but in the same query

Comment: `t1.*,t2.*,t3.*` I've tried to make a SELECT * for t1(produs),for t2(spec_laptop), for t3(spec_telefon)...I've also tried to SELECT just id_produs( foreign key) from t2 and t3... but with same result

Answer (score 0):

You joined them the wrong way, try this one :

```
SELECT * FROM produs as t1
inner join spec_laptop as t2 ON t2.id_produs = t1.id
inner join spec_telefon as t3 ON t3.id_produs = t1.id
WHERE t2.brand='Acer'
```

Comment: I've tried, but dosn't displays me anything. I have on laptop.php ('Acer','Asus','Lenovo') and on telefon.php ('Samsung','Apple','Sony')...WHEN I click Acer I want to select from spec_laptop, WHEN I click Samsung I want to select from spec_telefon....but have this on same query....That is because I have an OR in my code

Comment: btw, your database model is planed the bad way, you need to re-structure  it and add more tables, like categories, item_texts, item_prices, item_images, and merge them with IDs, then you will be able to select data very easily.

Comment: I have categories...I know i have started bad ,but it's almost done and i have to send this till Sunday..:D And I try to ask maybe someone have one idea..Thx for trying

Comment: I need to see your database model, then I could say what you should fix

Comment: this is bad that you have spec_laptop and spec_telefon tables, these are categories and better to have one more table were you store categories, and second table where you merge category id and product id, then you will get rid of those two telefon and laptop tables and you will select data much easier, because for now they are representing the categories